# How to switch from multiple Google OAuth consent screen to single page

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

Our company has changed to a new google account due to rebranding. We've created new project, OAuth consent screen and a client. Since then, our users presented with, what I call, multiple consent screen. They have to click on every single permission popup separately and then submit the summary page This is annoying. Previously, there was one page with all the scopes/permissions on it only. Examples attached:
Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Does anybody know what's going on and how to switch it back?
Thank you

Comment: the modal looks like an Android permission

Comment: It was Chrome on OsX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an announcement from Google. It's the change they made.

https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/more-granular-google-account.html

> We will show each permission that an app requests one at a time, within its own dialog, instead of presenting all permissions in a single dialog*. Users will have the ability to grant or deny permissions individually.